# Is it possible to add a form as an option in a HTML select tag?

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I am working on a **Todo** app with **Larave**l where the user can obviously *add tasks* and *specifies it's category*.

I want the user to be able to *add a category of his choice*, so when he clicks on the list of categories, **the last option** would be 'Add New Category' and **it has to be a form** so i can add the category to his list of categories (every user has his own list of categories).

I have tried this:

```
<form action="/tasks" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <input name="name" type=text" class="form-control" id="name">
            @if ($errors->has('name'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">{{$errors->first('name')}}</div>
            @endif
            <h5 class="card-title mt-3">Category</h5>
            <select name="category" class="form-control mt-3" id="category">
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{$category->id}}" @if ($loop->first) selected="selected" @endif>{{$category->name}}
                </option>
                @endforeach
                <option>
                    <form action="/category" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Add Categorie">
                    </form>
                </option>
            </select>
            @if ($errors->has('category'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger mt-2">{{$errors->first('category')}}</div>
            @endif
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-3">
                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Task
            </button>
        </form>
```

i didn't think it'll work but i just tried it and i had this result:

[image]

Comment: `<form>` inside `<form>` is invalid. Create a +button that opens a modal with a completely separate form to add a new category? Submit via AJAX, when successful, close modal and reload your `<select>` options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah You can use with ajax. Add a button with Catagory input filed and store category using ajax.